# Jquery Cycle add timeout at the last image before restart the loop

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cycle

The original code a use it : When all images show on cycle, I would like a pause before the loop restart again. So I try this with SetTimeout, but I think i don't use the good code.

My original code, work fine :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slideshow1').cycle({ 
  fx:     'none', 
  timeout: 100
  });
 });
```

What i would like to add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function()
 {
  $('.slideshow1').cycle({ 
  fx:     'none', 
  timeout: 100
  }, 5000);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `timeoutFn` option to provide a custom timeout for the last slide. From the [options reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) page:

```
timeoutFn:     null,  // callback for determining per-slide timeout value: 
                      // function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, 
                      // options, forwardFlag)
```

You will need to experiment a bit to figure out what `currSlideElement` and/or `nextSlideElement` will be on the last element, and if you see the last slide then return a longer timeout.

---

**Update**

Here is the working code written by user2440625:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow1').cycle({ 
    fx: 'none', 
    timeout: 100,
    timeoutFn : calculateTimeout
    });
}); 

function calculateTimeout(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    if  (index==8){ // position last image.
        return 5000; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I saw this but I don't know how to use. If I have 7 slides and at the last one I would like a pause 5 sec before restart. How I can use this function with timoutFn.

Comment: @user2440625 - See my updated answer with a code example. Does that help?

Comment: I test this code but is doesn't work, did you test this code? The 5000 secondes never coming at the end.

Comment: @user2440625 - `I have not tested the following code` - I think this is close to the code you want, but its up to you to test/debug and get it to work.